# Convenience initialization of UINavigationController subclass makes subclass constant init twice

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I have subclasses of `UINavigationController` and `UITableViewController`.

To initialize subclasses I decided to use some `convenience init` methods that call some designated initializer of the superclass. Also, each subclass has some `let` constant:

```
let someValue: SomeClass = SomeClass()
```

Each class is successfully initialized by calling its newly created `convenience init` method.

The problem is that the `let` constant is initialized **TWICE** in `UINavigationController` subclass.

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

final class Navigation: UINavigationController {
    convenience init(anyObject: Any) {
        self.init(rootViewController: UIViewController())
    }
    let service = Constant("Constant Initialization -> Navigation")
}

final class Table: UITableViewController {
    convenience init(anyObject: Any) {
        self.init(style: .plain)
    }
    let service = Constant("Constant Initialization -> Table")
}

class Constant: NSObject {
    init(_ string: String) {
        super.init()
        debugPrint(string)
    }
}

Navigation(anyObject: NSNull())
Table(anyObject: NSNull())
```

Are we allowed to use `convenience init` like above? Why?

**Why is the `convenience init` behavior is different in these two cases?**

Checked with: *Version 8.2 beta (8C30a)*, *Version 8.2 (8C38)*, *Version 8.2.1 (8C1002)*

P.S. Playground log of the code above:

```
"Constant Initialization -> Navigation"
"Constant Initialization -> Navigation"
"Constant Initialization -> Table"
```

Answer (score 4):

So this seems to be weirdly "expected behavior" with Swift. The reason it's happening is due to the constant initialized property `service`. Namely, this post summarizes the issue your seeing pretty well: [blog post](http://darrarski.pl/2014/12/not-initialize-objects-swift/)

Essentially, the Obj-C underlying super classes are leaking memory and your `service` property is initialized twice because of this pattern of Obj-C initialization:

```
- (id)init {
  self = [super init];
  if (self) {
    self = [[self.class alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
  }
  return self;
}
```

A simple solution to avoid this is the following pattern:

```
import UIKit

final class NavigationController: UINavigationController {
    var service: ObjectTest?

    convenience init() {
        self.init(rootViewController: UIViewController())
        self.service = ObjectTest("init nav")
    }
}
class ObjectTest: NSObject{
    init(_ string: String) {
        super.init()
        print(string)
    }
}
```

All that's changing from your implementation is initializing the `service` only after your class itself is initialized.

Another solution, though, is to use the designated initializer for the superclass your initializing. Meaning that you don't use a convenience initializer which would employ the above Obj-C initialization pattern.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. And I still don't don't understand why is the convenience init behavior is different in those two cases?

Comment: So the `convenience` initialization uses the above Objective-C example init pattern, where there's two init calls (`[super init]` and `[self.class alloc] init...]`. The designated initializer, from my understanding, would go directly into the `[self.class alloc] init...]` initializer path, and would therefore not double initialize, which is what causes the issue you're seeing.

Comment: I've thought that in both cases I call designated initializer, don't I?